# LEAST function using criteria query

Tags: java, jpa-2.0

I'm using this code to build a Expression:

```
Expression<Long> t = builder.function("least", Long.class, root.<Long>get("RId"), builder.<Long>literal(new Long(1)));
```

equivalent to :

```
LEAST(RId, 1)
```

but i got error :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.MethodNode
```

but if i use instead this:

```
Expression<Long> t = builder.function("trunc", Long.class, root.<Long>get("RId"));
```

it works. anyone can help?

Comment: Have you tried least() -  http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#least%28javax.persistence.criteria.Expression%29

Comment: no i dont want the aggregate function. i want to map each RId to 0,1